# How to show a logarithmic function set is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given a set $\mathcal{T}^N = \{f| f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} B_n \log_2 \Bigg (1 + 
\frac{ p_n }{ || x - x_n ||_2^{2} + 1} \Bigg), p_n, B_n \in \mathbb{R}^+\}$, where $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d $ is fixed. $B_n, p_n$ are unknown.

Is $\mathcal{T}^N $ a compact set? Can someone provide some possible directions?

Comment: What is the topology?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.